# How to link same set of libraries to multiple targets/executables in cmake?

Tags: cmake

I have multiple executable/target files in my project structure, and they all use the same libraries. Is there a way to make this more compact? Perhaps something like a for-loop?

```
set(ALL_LIBS lib1 lib2 lib3) # etc.

add_executable(program1 program1.cpp)
target_link_libraries(program1 PRIVATE ${ALL_LIBS})

add_executable(program2 program2.cpp)
target_link_libraries(program2 PRIVATE ${ALL_LIBS})

add_executable(program3 program3.cpp)
target_link_libraries(program3 PRIVATE ${ALL_LIBS})

add_executable(program4 program4.cpp)
target_link_libraries(program4 PRIVATE ${ALL_LIBS})
```

I'm looking for a solution that achieves something similar or cleaner than this:

```
add_executable(program1 program1.cpp)
add_executable(program2 program2.cpp)
add_executable(program3 program3.cpp)
add_executable(program4 program4.cpp)

# somehow get list of target names
foreach(${TARGETS})
    # link libraries to each target
    target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE ${ALL_LIBS})
endforeach()
```

Comment: You can use `foreach` and `macro` commands for that.

Comment: @arrowd how would you suggest bundling the target name and path? I don't think cmake directly supports tuples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may define your own macro or function which defines an executable like normal `add_executable` but also links the executable with the common libraries.

```
set(ALL_LIBS lib1 lib2 lib3) # etc.

# A wrapper around add_executable which links all created executables with libraries
function(add_executable_common name)
  # Forward all parameters to add_executable
  add_executable(${ARGV})
  # Perform additional actions
  target_link_libraries(${name} PRIVATE ${ALL_LIBS})
endfunction()

# Created function can be used in the very same manner as add_executable.

add_executable_common(program1 program1.cpp)
add_executable_common(program2 program2.cpp)
add_executable_common(program3 program3.cpp)
add_executable_common(program4 program4.cpp)
```

---

CMake variables `ARGV` and `ARGN` provide a perfect way to **forward** parameters of one function/macro to another.
This allows to easily create wrappers to existed functions without needs to parse all parameters needed for the wrapped function.

E.g. while the function `add_executable_common`, defined above, doesn't parse parameters except the first one, it still can be used for define a STATIC or SHARED library and can be used for define a library with several sources:

```
add_executable_common(program5 SHARED program5.cpp additional_algos.cpp)
```

Comment: Thank you. I came to the same conclusion but you explained it much better.

Answer (score 1):

I found an okay solution to reduce line count. I just created a function to accept target name and file paths.

```
function(add_program_target TARGET_NAME)
    add_executable(${TARGET_NAME} ${ARGN})
    target_link_libraries(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE ${ALL_LIBS})
endfunction()
```

Then I just add targets like this:

```
add_program_target(program1 program1.cpp helper.cpp)
add_program_target(program2 program2.cpp)
add_program_target(program2 program3.cpp)
add_program_target(program2 program4.cpp)
# etc.
```

Comment: Yup, this is exactly how this should be solved.